# MS-Access controls not visible until after first click

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have put some controls (buttons, labels and text boxes) on top of a navigation control, on top of the navigation buttons. These controls strangely only appear after clicking anywhere on the form. 
Any thoughts on avoiding this problem?

Comment: Works for me. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Thanks for checkinng this out. I could replicate even with brand new databases: create a new navigation form, vertical tabs, left. Create a button or field that sits on top of the navigation control, but is not a control in the navigation control. The on-top control appears only after a click on the navigation...

Comment: Okay, tested again. Command button hides behind tab when tab area is clicked after clicking records area. Sorry, can't help. Why would you want to do this anyway?